# How to Customize the time format for Python logging?

Tags: python, datetime, logging, formatting, python-logging

I am new to Python's logging package and plan to use it for my project. I would like to customize the time format to my taste. Here is a short code I copied from a tutorial:

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger("logging_tryout2")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create console handler and set level to debug
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s")

# add formatter to ch
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

# add ch to logger
logger.addHandler(ch)

# "application" code
logger.debug("debug message")
logger.info("info message")
logger.warn("warn message")
logger.error("error message")
logger.critical("critical message")
```

And here is the output:

```
2010-07-10 10:46:28,811;DEBUG;debug message
2010-07-10 10:46:28,812;INFO;info message
2010-07-10 10:46:28,812;WARNING;warn message
2010-07-10 10:46:28,812;ERROR;error message
2010-07-10 10:46:28,813;CRITICAL;critical message
```

I would like to shorten the time format to just: '`2010-07-10 10:46:28`', dropping the mili-second suffix. I looked at the Formatter.formatTime, but I am confused.

Answer (score 344, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter) regarding the Formatter class:

> The constructor takes two optional arguments: a message format string and a date format string.

So change

```
# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s")
```

to

```
# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s",
                              "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Note that if you're using the dictConfig method of configuring logging (e.g. if you're using Django), you can set this using the 'datefmt' dict key for a formatter. See:
[Django Logging Configuration](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) , [logging module: Dictionary Schema Details](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details)

Comment: Also, if your configuring logging with basicConfig, it takes a named parameter called datefmt

Comment: In 1.9, if you are using a LOGGING setting, you can include a 'datefmt' entry like this ... `'formatters': {
    'default': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s | %(levelname)s | %(module)s | %(message)s',
        'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
    },`

Comment: what will be the time zone ?

Comment: @Luv33preet its '%z'

Answer (score 318):

Using `logging.basicConfig`, the following example works for me:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='HISTORYlistener.log',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s',
    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
)
```

This allows you to format & config all in one line. A resulting log record looks as follows:

```
2014-05-26 12:22:52.376 CRITICAL historylistener - main: History log failed to start
```

Comment: I've added zero-padded formatting for the msecs field. Otherwise, msecs values less than 100 appear incorrectly.

Comment: That said, the OP doesn't want msecs to appear at all!

Comment: To remove milli secs just remove this in format -->  .%(msecs)03d

Comment: My favorite format: `datefmt='%0y%0m%0d_%0H%0M%0S'`

Answer (score 65):

To add to the other answers, here is the [variable list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) from Python Documentation.

```
Directive   Meaning Notes

%a  Locale’s abbreviated weekday name.   
%A  Locale’s full weekday name.  
%b  Locale’s abbreviated month name.     
%B  Locale’s full month name.    
%c  Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.   
%d  Day of the month as a decimal number [01,31].    
%H  Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number [00,23].    
%I  Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number [01,12].    
%j  Day of the year as a decimal number [001,366].   
%m  Month as a decimal number [01,12].   
%M  Minute as a decimal number [00,59].  
%p  Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM. (1)
%S  Second as a decimal number [00,61]. (2)
%U  Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.    (3)
%w  Weekday as a decimal number [0(Sunday),6].   
%W  Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number [00,53]. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.    (3)
%x  Locale’s appropriate date representation.    
%X  Locale’s appropriate time representation.    
%y  Year without century as a decimal number [00,99].    
%Y  Year with century as a decimal number.   
%z  Time zone offset indicating a positive or negative time difference from UTC/GMT of the form +HHMM or -HHMM, where H represents decimal hour digits and M represents decimal minute digits [-23:59, +23:59].  
%Z  Time zone name (no characters if no time zone exists).   
%%  A literal '%' character.
```

Comment: Strange. I want to have a custom date format, but I want to include the microseconds (or is it milliseconds?). `%S` is meant to be "as a decimal number", but according to my experiments it prints as an integer (no decimal part).

Comment: @mikerodent see the accepted answer. To also included milliseconds you need something like `%(msecs)03d`. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes).

Answer (score 41):

if using logging.config.fileConfig with a configuration file use something like:

```
[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Answer (score 8):

### Try These Formats:

**Format 1:**

```
'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : '%(asctime)s |:| LEVEL: %(levelname)s |:| FILE PATH: %(pathname)s |:| FUNCTION/METHOD: %(funcName)s %(message)s |:| LINE NO.: %(lineno)d |:| PROCESS ID: %(process)d |:| THREAD ID: %(thread)d',
            'datefmt' : "%y/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
                    },
              }
```

**Output of Format 1:**

[image]

**Format 2:**

```
'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : '%(asctime)s |:| LEVEL: %(levelname)s |:| FILE PATH: %(pathname)s |:| FUNCTION/METHOD: %(funcName)s %(message)s |:| LINE NO.: %(lineno)d |:| PROCESS ID: %(process)d |:| THREAD ID: %(thread)d',
            'datefmt' : "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
                    },
              }
```

**Output of Format 2:**

[image]

Comment: Could you add some code which shows how to use it?

Answer (score 4):

In order to customize time format while logging we can create a logger object and and a fileHandler to it.

```
        import logging
        from datetime import datetime

        logger = logging.getLogger("OSA")

        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        filename = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + ".log"
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(filename, mode="a")#'a' for append you can use 'w' for write

        formatter = logging.Formatter(
            "%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : [%(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s()] : %(message)s",
            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```