# Python How to create wrapper over print or logging

Tags: python

I want to create wrapper over print function or any logging function so that if internally I need to change logging/print strategy it should work without changing in all module.For ex:

```
print "Hello this is test A:%d B:%d C:%d",a,b,c
```

instead of this it should look like:

```
MyPrint "Hello this is test A:%d B:%d C:%d",a,b,c
```

which will give me same output.

This gives me flexiblity of changing definition of MyPrint without affecting print in whole code.

In C++ this can be acheived through macro but not sure how we can achieve in python.

Comment: Isn't this more or less what [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) is for? Minus the syntax of the `print` statement.

Comment: You could also later replace `sys.stdout` (where `print` writes to) with a different object.

Comment: refer to @Omar's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing something like this should do:

```
def my_print(message, *args):
    print(message % args)
```

Then you could call it like this:

```
my_print("Hello this is test A:%d B:%d C:%d", 1, 2, 3)

# Output: Hello this is test A:1 B:2 C:3
```

Comment: Why not just forward the parameters as they are and call `print(*args, **kwargs)` from a `my_print(*args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: It would leave the string formatting to the called `print` function (not the print statement, though).

Comment: Not sure if I tested the code as you suggested, but the test outputs `Hello this is test A:%d B:%d C:%d 1 2 3`

Comment: @OmarEinea yes this is output that  I was getting.

Comment: @OmarEinea with ndim suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should be using `logging` with a custom `format`

eg. as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220312/1219006) shows

```
# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s",
                              "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: no this is not what I was looking for, lets say I am using this logger, with some syntax say logging.error("Content") but in future if I need to change logger then I have to change all the logging.error() lines , so to overcome this if I have my logger("Content ") than I wont need to change code I need to change logger() handling logic.

Comment: @AnonymousDev I don't get how this doesn't solve your problem? Your example was a bit unclear to me

Comment: lets say I am using logger of x package but in future I need to change to logger of some y package , so I need to create a wrapper that will handle logging and since in code will be using my wrapper apis so there wont be change if I need to change logger of x to y package. Refer to ans that might clear your doubt.

Comment: @AnonymousDev Everyone just uses the python `logging` module. If they were to use another logging module, theyd just use that from the start. Nobody really switches between them