# What does each word of the formatter signify? like the -8s?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, timestamp, epoch

Python logger shows as below :

```
consoleformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] %(message)s')
```

I want to read my log file timestamp to make more sense of it. Cant get a headstart to convert the time, though this is the format it's specified in.

Say for example my log says timestamp : 0063730209 How do I read it in human readable form?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220284/how-to-customize-the-time-format-for-python-logging

Comment: I already went through the above link, It does not answer my question, As the link provided allows us to customize the format of the date display. My question is rather simple to know how I can convert a timestamp I found in my Log file to a human readable time. EPOCH converter gave me a timestamp of 1972, which is weird, So I need to know the reason for the syntax of the timestamp [%(levelname)-8s]