# How to change date format for Django logging?

Tags: python, django, logging

The comments in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220312/5359531) say that you should be able to customize the date format for logging in Django:

> Note that if you're using the dictConfig method of configuring logging (e.g. if you're using Django), you can set this using the 'datefmt' dict key for a formatter. See: Django Logging Configuration , logging module: Dictionary Schema Details

However, it does not work:

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'django.server': { # duplicate of default for django.server
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[{server_time}] {message}',
            'style': '{',
            'datefmt' : '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            }
}
```

This does not work either:

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'datefmt' : '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            },
}
```

In both cases, I still get the default logging date format:

```
[13/Mar/2019 21:53:05] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16808
```

Note that in the source code, the `datefmt` should have been passed on and used, but it appears that this is not the case:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/782d85b6dfa191e67c0f1d572641d8236c79174c/django/utils/log.py#L190

Using Python 3.6 and Django 2.1

---

Update:

When I include this in my `settings.py` as described:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'django.server': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
            'format': '[{server_time}] {message}',
            'datefmt' : '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
            'style': '{',
        }
}
```

And then edit the file `conda//lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/log.py` like this:

```
class ServerFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.style = color_style()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("self.datefmt", self.datefmt)
```

I get messages in my console that look like this, indicating that I actually am propagating the `datefmt` correctly:

```
$ python manage.py runserver
self.datefmt %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
self.datefmt %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 13, 2019 - 23:43:50
Django version 2.1.2, using settings 'webapp.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[13/Mar/2019 23:45:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 16808
```

Maybe the error has to do with this line in `django/utils/log.py`?

```
if self.uses_server_time() and not hasattr(record, 'server_time'):
            record.server_time = self.formatTime(record, self.datefmt)
```

^ No matter what I do, it appears that this check never gets tripped, because `not hasattr(record, 'server_time')` always evaluates to `False`, because `record` already has `server_time` by default, and it appears to come from this section of Django code in `django/core/servers/basehttp.py`:

```
class WSGIRequestHandler(simple_server.WSGIRequestHandler):
...
...
    def log_message(self, format, *args):
        extra = {
            'request': self.request,
            'server_time': self.log_date_time_string(),
        }
```

Where `simple_server.WSGIRequestHandler.log_date_time_string()` is coming from the `wsgiref` package. However, that package does not contain any reference to the function `log_date_time_string()`, it appears to be coming directly from the Python builtin `http` library (`conda//lib/python3.6/http/server.py`):

```
def log_date_time_string(self):
    """Return the current time formatted for logging."""
    now = time.time()
    year, month, day, hh, mm, ss, x, y, z = time.localtime(now)
    s = "%02d/%3s/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d" % (
            day, self.monthname[month], year, hh, mm, ss)
    return s
```

^ The date format here is hard-coded into the library, does not appear to be changeable.

So... how is any of this supposed to work? Am I missing something? Is this some sort of bug in Django? Unless I am mistaken there is no way to override this `datefmt` based on this?

Comment: Shouldn't that dictionary be ```DEFAULT_LOGGING``` instead?

Comment: changing it to `DEFAULT_LOGGING` does not appear to make a difference for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a good, detailed investigation. Make sure that your research includes the Django ticket tracker. The first hit on a search for `site:code.djangoproject.com datefmt` reveals that this is a [known bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29329).

That ticket shows a possible workaround—use `asctime` instead of `server_time`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to use the attribute `asctime` instead of `server_time`, e.g.

```
           'format': '[{asctime}] {message}',`
           'datefmt' : '%Y-%m-%d',`
```

I think `server_time` is a modified attribute used by the logger 'django'. When I tried to format log messages for the logger 'root' with `server_time`, I get an error indicating that the attribute `server_time` is not recognized.

```
    raise ValueError('Formatting field not found in record: %s' % e)
ValueError: Formatting field not found in record: 'server_time'
```

I think `server_time` is a formatted string value generated from `asctime` and provided by django logger, and therefore it does not work try to modify it again with `datefmt`.

`datefmt` works fine to modify the attribute `asctime`