# How to set a datetime fixed value as result in Python Logger?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating some structured logging for my application and I wanna check the output of it. For the logging, I'm using Python default logger and pytests for the tests (unittest is not an option in this project). 
  I wanna assert the output I get from the logging against a fixed text and in order to do it I need to have a fixed datetime. But doesn't matter what I do I can't override the Python Logger datetime.  How can I mock the datetime I get from the python logger in order to have a proper test?

**Update**

It's not a formater that I need, I actually need the expected Datetime as result always when I run the tests. So how many times I call the logger, it will always respond with the same Datetime Value, for instance: `2001-01-01`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it helps.

```
def sim_time(self, record, datefmt=None):
    return datetime.datetime(2000,1,2,3,4,5,678).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f')[:-3]

import logging
logging.Formatter.formatTime = sim_time
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new formatter

```py
# create formatter
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s;%(levelname)s;%(message)s",
                              "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

See [How to Customize the time format for Python logging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220284/how-to-customize-the-time-format-for-python-logging)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the datetime format, but datetime value.