# How to create date timestamp logs like git log

Tags: python, datetime

Using `datetime.datetime.now()`, I receive some badly formatted timestamps.

Is there an intuitive way of creating a date timestamp in this format?

```
Wed Aug 7 13:38:59 2019 -0500
```

This is seen in git log.

Comment: Have a look at the `strftime()` method of `datetime` instance objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print a date in a regular format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311627/how-to-print-a-date-in-a-regular-format)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: If you are using this for logging it's best to use a [log formatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220284/how-to-customize-the-time-format-for-python-logging) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strftime()` to format dates as shown below:

```
from datetime import datetime
d = '2019-08-07 13:38:59-0500'
d2 = datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')
d3 = d2.strftime('%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z')
print(d3)
```

This returns:

```
Wed Aug 07 13:38:59 2019 -050000
```

[This](http://strftime.org/) website is a great resource for `strftime` formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the datetime library. Using strftime, you can rewrite the datetime object into a nicely formatted string.

In your case, you are going for `Wed Aug 7 13:38:59 2019 -0500`, which translated to strftime formatting is `"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z"`.

Overall, it'd be

```
datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %z")
```

Which will give a string that looks like 'Wed Aug 7 13:38:59 2019 -0500'.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

if __name__ == "__main__":
    time = strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())
    print(time)
```

This was found on the documentation page of the time module. There are also a lot of additional features you might be interested in using outlined here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime